# Баг с шириной слайда в слайдере при просмотре видео с youtube в полноэкранном режиме

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, owl-carousel

Есть два плагина-слайдера: owl carousel и slick.
Оба выдают этот баг: включаю видео с youtube в полноэкранном режиме с iPhone / iPad , выключаю и вуаля - ширина слайда стала просто огромной!
http://prntscr.com/ld504m

На десктопе проблемы нет, но баг так же отлавливается в chrome на ширине примерно 768pxю

Что я делаю не так???

Comment: Сделайте пример на https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @ViacheslavSoldatov нашел решение, сейчас скину в ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение в обоих слайдерах:
welcome box - обертка слайдера

slick: `$('.welcome__box').slick("setPosition");`

owl carousel: `$('.welcome__box').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');`